# Dynamixel motors not found

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm going through [this tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/dynamixel_controllers/Tutorials/ConnectingToDynamixelBus) about connecting/ running Dynamixel servos through ROS (these are AX-12 servos).
In step 3.Step 2: Create a launch file for the manager node, I created a .launch file as instructed by copy-pasting the supplied code in to a new file named controller_manager.launch.
After executing the command "roslaunch dynamixel_tutorials controller_manager.launch", I receive an error. The error states
[FATAL] [WAllTime: 13151009139.949289] pan_tilt_port: No motors found

The error log file referenced states the same information, the motors can not be "pinged" and therefore the process is killed.

Running the command
ls -la /dev/ttyUSB*

Gives me crw-rw-r-- 1 turtlebot 188, 0 Oct 23 11:18 /dev/ttyUSB0

lsusb gives me
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0403:6001 Future Technology Devices...

So it looks like the computer "sees" the USB connector. I've even tried a different motor and different power supply...

Any ideas?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46612/dynamixel-motors-not-found/) by [joe.s](https://answers.ros.org/users/3410/joe.s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 162 on 2012-10-23

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [arebgun](https://answers.ros.org/users/18/arebgun/) on 2012-10-29**:
What version of ROS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have updated the tutorial to work with Electric and Fuerte version of the dynamixel_motor stack.

---

Originally posted by [arebgun](https://answers.ros.org/users/18/arebgun/) with karma: 2121 on 2012-10-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The USB port isn't set to writable. Run `sudo chmod a+rw /dev/ttyUSB0` to make it writable by all users.

You can add a udev rule to make USB ports be writable by all users by default. Make a file called `75-usb-rw.rules` in `/etc/udev/rules.d` and add the following to it:

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", KERNEL=="ttyACM[0-9]*", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", KERNEL=="ttyUSB[0-9]*", MODE="0666"
```

---

Originally posted by [Elizabeth C](https://answers.ros.org/users/3009/elizabeth-c/) with karma: 138 on 2012-12-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1